# Key-Value store with master-master replication support

Tags: node.js, embedded-database, key-value-store, multi-master-replication

I'm looking for file-based embedded store for Node.js with following features:

1. Support for master-master replication that replicates real time changes so you can easily
   have a cluster of node.js processes (on several servers) where you can read or write to
   any of them. An appropriate conflict-resolution mechanism should be thought of.
2. Support for both JSON and binary values
3. Non-memory-based

Comment: No key-value store found. Use document based stores: CouchDB